# How to substitute variable in backtick command in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl

I am trying to make a curl call in my rails application for sentimental analysis as shown here https://algorithmia.com/algorithms/nlp/SentimentAnalysis

```
text =   "I love coding"
secret = "yv5julwo8l7biwuni62r37t823igd87d97u623568yf"

result = `curl -X POST -d '"#{text}"' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Simple #{secret}' https://api.algorithmia.com/v1/algo/nlp/SentimentAnalysis/0.1.2`
result = JSON.parse(result)
```

But inside the back-tick, its not substituting the value correctly. So how to substitute the variable in this curl command?

When I execute this code with `I love coding`, I get response `0` while on their website, I get `2` ( that is correct), so that makes me believe its not substituting the variable value properly.

Comment: Are the back ticks necessary in this case?  Have you tried using double quotes instead?

Comment: dtj, back-tick is necessary for executing any system command directly.

Comment: back-ticks are one of many ways to execute a system command. They're the easiest, but hardly the most flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When making a system call with anything but the simplest arguments you should always use the [Shellwords](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html) library to ensure that your arguments are properly escaped and/or quoted. For example:

```
require "shellwords"

text = '"I love coding"'
secret = "yv5julwo8l7biwuni62r37t823igd87d97u623568yf"

args = [ "-X", "POST",
         "-d", text,
         "-H", "Content-Type: application/json",
         "-H", "Authorization: Simple #{secret}",
         "https://api.algorithmia.com/v1/algo/nlp/SentimentAnalysis/0.1.2" ]

data = `curl #{args.shelljoin}`
result = JSON.parse(data)
```

And, as the Tin Man points out above, backticks are neither the only nor necessarily best way to make system calls in Ruby. I highly recommend reading this series of articles: https://devver.wordpress.com/2009/06/30/a-dozen-or-so-ways-to-start-sub-processes-in-ruby-part-1/

Lastly, making a system call to curl isn't generally the best way to make an HTTP request from Ruby when gems like rest-client, faraday and httparty are available, not to mention Net::HTTP in the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is an error in you api-key. Your code is working as is with my api-key.

Edit:

Code is working as is as shown in this:

[image]

Edit 2:

```
require 'json'

text =   'I love coding'
secret = 'secret'

result = `curl -X POST -d '"#{text}"' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Simple #{secret}' https://api.algorithmia.com/v1/algo/nlp/SentimentAnalysis/0.1.2`
result = JSON.parse(result)

puts result
```

Comment: Thomas, I did not post my real key here LOL. Did you try this with your key and compare the output with what you can get directly on their website? You will find difference, as `"I love coding"` returns 0 while on their site it returns 2. So I assume the string is not getting escaped from ruby

Comment: Can you post your ruby code here too with variable substitution, as I have?